# Update a NULL datetime column from PHP form

Tags: php

So I've been trying possible solutions but didn't get any success. I wanted to UPDATE the "timeOut" column (which has a NULL value) at the end of the day. I wanted to change it from NULL to whatever is filled on the form.
Here's my php code:

```
<?php

require '../system/database.php';

    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $id = null;
    if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    }
    if (null==$id){
        header("Location:record.php");
    }
    if ($_POST) {       
         //$Name = $_POST['name'];
         //$TimeIn = $_POST['timeIn'];
        //$TimeIn = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($TimeIn));
        $TimeOut = $_POST['timeOut'];
        $TimeOut = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($TimeOut));
        $valid = true;
        if ($valid){
             $sql = "UPDATE attendance SET timeOut = ? WHERE id = ?"; 
             $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
             $q->execute(array($TimeOut,$id));
             header('location:record.php');
        }
     }else{
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE id = ?";
         $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
         $q->execute(array($id));
         $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         $Name = $data['name'];
         $TimeIn = $data['timeIn'];
         $TimeOut = $data['timeOut'];
         Database::disconnect();
     }
?>
```

and here's my php form

```
<form action="edit-record.php" method="post" role="form">
  <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
          <label for="name">Name of Employee</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="name" readonly>
            <option selected="selected"><?php echo !empty($Name)?$Name:'';?></option>
          </select>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
             <label for="timeIn">Date/ Time In</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="timeIn" readonly value="<?php echo !empty($TimeIn)?$TimeIn:'';?>">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
             <label for="timeOut">Date/ Time Out</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' name="timeOut">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-sm-1">
             <label for="timeSubmit" style="color:white">Submit</label>
             <button type="button submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Set Time Out</button>
     </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: it's supposed to update my database, but it's not, my "timeOut" column remains null

Comment: for test, set $timeOut manually(to make sure the DataBase part is all right)

Comment: the id depends on which row is selected, I only need to update the timeout of the selected row that's why I didn't set a value for the id

Comment: @AminShojaei tried to do it manually on sql, and it's working fine. My column is updating. but when it comes from the form, it won't change

Comment: @Richelle what did you get in your `$_POST['timeOut']`. And upon checking you form has the `type="button submit"`. Either submit / button is possible but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues. The first is that your debugging methods are failing you, you have `header('location:record.php')` twice, both for an error and success. Additionally, after every `header` you should have an `exit` so the code stops firing. As the code currently is written even with the error state the `update` still fires but (error #2) since `$id` is set to `NULL` because your form has no `id` value the `where` matches no records and no `update` occurs.

So your PHP should be:

```
<?php
    require '../system/database.php';
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    
    $id = null;
    if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    }
    if (null==$id){
        header("Location:record.php");
        //header("Location:record.php?status=no+id");
        exit();
    }
    if ($_POST) {       
        //$Name = $_POST['name'];
        //$TimeIn = $_POST['timeIn'];
        //$TimeIn = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($TimeIn));
        $TimeOut = $_POST['timeOut'];
        $TimeOut = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($TimeOut));
        $valid = true;
        if ($valid){
             $sql = "UPDATE attendance SET timeOut = ? WHERE id = ?"; 
             $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
             $q->execute(array($TimeOut,$id));
             header('location:record.php');
             //header('location:record.php?status=update+fired');
             exit();
        }
     }else{
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE id = ?";
         $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
         $q->execute(array($id));
         $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         $Name = $data['name'];
         $TimeIn = $data['timeIn'];
         $TimeOut = $data['timeOut'];
         Database::disconnect();
     }
?>
```

and then your HTML should be (presuming these are on the same page, if not change `$id` to the id variable):

```
<form action="edit-record.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" method="post" role="form">
  <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
          <label for="name">Name of Employee</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="name" readonly>
            <option selected="selected"><?php echo !empty($Name)?$Name:'';?></option>
          </select>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
             <label for="timeIn">Date/ Time In</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="timeIn" readonly value="<?php echo !empty($TimeIn)?$TimeIn:'';?>">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
             <label for="timeOut">Date/ Time Out</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' name="timeOut">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-sm-1">
             <label for="timeSubmit" style="color:white">Submit</label>
             <button type="button submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Set Time Out</button>
     </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

alternatively to get in `POST`

```
<form action="edit-record.php" method="post" role="form">
      <div class="form-row">
         <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
              <label for="name">Name of Employee</label>
              <select class="form-control" name="name" readonly>
                <option selected="selected"><?php echo !empty($Name)?$Name:'';?></option>
              </select>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                 <label for="timeIn">Date/ Time In</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="timeIn" readonly value="<?php echo !empty($TimeIn)?$TimeIn:'';?>">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                 <label for="timeOut">Date/ Time Out</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' name="timeOut">
         </div>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id;?>" name="id" />
         <div class="form-group col-sm-1">
                 <label for="timeSubmit" style="color:white">Submit</label>
                 <button type="button submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Set Time Out</button>
         </div>
       </div>
    </form>
```

Additionally see commented out `header` calls. I would use those and on `record.php` look at `$_GET['status']` to see what occurs.

Comment: Totally missed the `?id=<?php echo $id;?` on my form action. will keep the other key points on mind. Thank you so much!